# two dimension array square elements using map and pass it for further processing python

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

Trying to pass a two dimension array of dynamic size as an iter 
Square all the values in the array using a map 
Process it further to output the code in human readable format.

```
#array to be converted
arr = [[ 1, 2, 6], [3, 4],[6,8,9,0]]

def lambdaMap(arr):
    ans = map(pp3, arr)
    return ans

# return the list with all elements squared and pass it to lambdaMap
def pp3(vv):
    for i in range(len(str(vv))):
        for j in range(len(str(vv[i]))):
            vv[i][j] = int( vv[i][j] ) ** 2
    return vv


if __name__ == '__main__':

    d = []

    ans = lambdaMap(arr)
    for row in ans:
       print(' '.join(map(str, row)))
```

**Error returned**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 22, in <module>
    for row in ans:
  File "stack.py", line 11, in pp3
    vv[i][j] = int( vv[i][j] ) ** 2
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable***
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
#array to be converted
arr = [[ 1, 2, 6], [3, 4],[6,8,9,0]]

def lambdaMap(arr):
    ans = map(pp3, [arr])
    return ans

# return the list with all elements squared and pass it to lambdaMap
def pp3(vv):
    for i in range(len(vv)):
        for j in range(len(vv[i])):
            vv[i][j] = int( vv[i][j] ) ** 2
    return vv


if __name__ == '__main__':

    d = []

    ans = lambdaMap(arr)
    for row in ans:
       print(' '.join(map(str, row)))
```